# How to start video quick on a JFrame using JMF

Tags: java, swing, jmf

Can anyone please tell me which is the best way to play video in a JPanel.I am currently working on a learning software for children where some learning videos will be played upon selection.Videos are stored in some folder.I have successfully done the job using JMF but the problem is its kinda slow.It takes some time to start the video, though the videos are not too large(2-4 MB).What can i do to make it quick-start,

Thank u

```
public class MediaPanel extends JPanel
{
public static boolean playing = false;
public static Player mediaPlayer;
public MediaPanel( URL mediaURL )
{
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // use a BorderLayout
// Use lightweight components for Swing compatibility

//Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
} // end MediaPanel constructor
public void play(URL mediaURL) throws NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException,               IOException, IncompatibleSourceException{
Manager.setHint( Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true );
System.out.println("sdfdsg");
mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );
Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
if ( video != null )
add( video);
mediaPlayer.start();
playing=true;
}
public void stop(){
mediaPlayer.stop();
playing = false;
}
public void play_one(){
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.start();
}
}
public class MediaPanel extends JPanel
{
public static boolean playing = false;
public static Player mediaPlayer;
public MediaPanel( URL mediaURL )
{
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); 

} // end MediaPanel constructor
public void play(URL mediaURL) throws NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException,     IOException, IncompatibleSourceException{
Manager.setHint( Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true );
mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );
Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
if ( video != null )
add( video);
mediaPlayer.start();
playing=true;
}
public void stop(){
mediaPlayer.stop();
playing = false;
}
public void play_one(){
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.start();
}
}
```

and the portion of the source code where i used this class..

```
try {
Home.text.setText("wait..");
if(Home.mediaPanel.playing==true)
Home.mediaPanel.stop();
Home.mediaPanel.play(new     URL("file://C://Users//zubair//workspace//learningKit//"+Home.selected_topic+"//"+Home.sele cted_group+"//v"+k+".flv"));
} catch (Exception e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JMF is from the stone-age. Do you have any reasons to stick to it?

I would recommend using JavaFX which has media support including video playing. JavaFX is part of Java 8, and is also shipped with Java 7 (just not on the default classpath). You can play a supported video format (*.flv, *.mp4) with just a few lines of code, and it also uses hardware acceleration if available.

Basically you only need to create a `Media`, a `MediaPlayer` and a `MediaView` class:

```
Media m = new Media(Paths.get("example.flv").toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);
// Add the mediaview component somewhere to your GUI
// And you're done. You can start playing the video by:
mp.play();
```

Here is a short, complete example application which plays a video:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/FullScreenVideoPlayer.htm

**Official Oracle tutorial:**

[Introduction to JavaFX Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXMD101)

Comment: where is everyone? no upvotes at the moment?